# Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow with Inputs.EventSource

Tags: event-flow, ms-tracing-eventsource

I am trying to use *EventSource* with *Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow* and I cannot make it output to the console. Here is an example where it works with *Inputs.Trace* but does not work with *Inputs.EventSource*:

myEventFLowConfig.json:

```
{
"type": "EventSource",

"sources": [
    {
        "providerName": "MyCompanyEventSource"
    }
],

"inputs":
[
    {
        "type": "EventSource",
        "traceLevel": "Warning"
    },
    {
        "type": "Trace",
        "traceLevel": "Warning"
    }
],

"outputs": [
    {
        "type": "StdOutput"
    }
]
```

}

MyEventSource.cs

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyCompanyEventSource")]
public class MyEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static MyEventSource Log = new MyEventSource();

    [Event(250, Message = "MESSAGE FROM EVENT SOURCE", Level = EventLevel.Warning)]
    public void MessageFromEventSource()
    {
        WriteEvent(250);
    }
}
```

console app:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var pipeline = DiagnosticPipelineFactory.CreatePipeline("myEventFlowConfig.json"))
        {
            SomeMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");                
            Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
        }

    }

    private static void SomeMethod()
    {
        MyEventSource.Log.MessageFromEventSource();
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("MESSAGE FROM TRACE");
    }
}
```

in the console app, I am using both *EventSource* and *Trace* as inputs, however only the *Trace* one is shown in the console. What am I doing wrong with the *EventSource* that it does not show up in the console?

Thanks!

Comment: the EventFlow on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and that was the configuration file. The sources part should go inside of the *inputs* part. So, there should be only *inputs* and *outputs* collection in the configuration file. The working configuration for the *EventSource* as the input, and *StdOutput* as output looks like this:

myEventFlowConfig.json:

```
{
"inputs": [
    {
        "type": "EventSource",
        "sources": [
            {
                "providerName": "MyCompanyEventSource",
                "traceLevel": "Warning"
            }
        ]
    }
],

"outputs": [
    {
        "type": "StdOutput"
    }
]
}
```